# Excel Formula returning Unexpected Results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

Formula in question:

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(Roster[Number],[@Number]),COUNTIF(Roster[Black List],"TRUE")),"TRUE","FALSE")`

The idea here is to check if any row is "black listed" on one table by comparing the "Number" columns on it and the Roster. The "Black List" column on the Roster is generated by checking two other columns on the Roster:

`=IF(OR([@Quarantined]="TRUE",[@[Leave In Place]]="TRUE"),"TRUE","FALSE")`

The problem is that no matter what I seem to do, the initial formula returns "FALSE" for all rows checked even though the Roster contains exact matches of the Numbers and a value of "TRUE" in the Black List column.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Try: `=COUNTIFS(Roster[Number],[@Number],Roster[Black List],TRUE)>0`

Comment: Remove the quotes from `TRUE` and `FALSE` - these are kind of variables not text - except you have written them explicitly into the cells

Comment: Similarly, `OR([@Quarantined],[@[Leave In Place]])`. You want to work with and return actual booleans, not text-that-looks-like-a-boolean.

Comment: Both your COUNTIFs return a number, let's say `1` and `3` so your formula says `IF(AND(1,3),"TRUE","FALSE")`. Also the TRUE and FALSE are already the output of IF, so no need mentioning them at all and if you do, no need to return them as "text". If you can share some sample data and required outcome, we may be able to help you further.

Comment: This is all on my work computer so I'll give it a shot on Monday. @Ike - I write them as strings because I seem to remember having issues using conditional formatting with Booleans